# Linkerd sidecar Injection

Tags: docker, kubernetes, linkerd

I could not get around, how to inject Linkerd sidecar to a docker yaml file and save it to a different file name. Honestly i have tried to go through linkerd docs but could not really get the idea. Following commands did not help me to understand:-

```
# Inject all the deployments in the default namespace.
kubectl get deploy -o yaml | linkerd inject - | kubectl apply -f -

# Injecting a file from a remote URL
linkerd inject http://url.to/yml | kubectl apply -f -

# Inject all the resources inside a folder and its sub-folders.
linkerd inject <folder> | kubectl apply -f -
```

I want to inject linkerd sidecar to a docker yaml like following command, which helps me to inject istio sidecar to a docker yaml file and save it in different file name:-

```
istioctl kube-inject -f deployment.yaml -o deployment-injected.yaml
```

Comment: Everywhere you say "Docker" here, do you actually mean "Kubernetes"?  Have you tried just taking the `kubectl apply` parts of those commands off?

Answer (score 2):

`linkerd inject` modifies resources to include the `linkerd.io/inject: enabled` annotation. If you want to store this modified version, you can use simple shell redirection like:

```
:; linkerd inject deploy.yml >deploy-annotated.yml

namespace "myns" injected
service "mysvc" skipped
deployment "mydeploy" injected
:; diff deploy.yml deploy-annotated.yml
17a18,19
>   annotations:
>     linkerd.io/inject: enabled
72a75,76
>       annotations:
>         linkerd.io/inject: enabled
```

This uses Linkerd's proxy-injector admission controller to add sidecar containers at pod-creation time.

Alternatively, you can "manually" inject the proxy locally, though this is generally discouraged, since it prevents your application from automatically getting new proxy versions & configuration. Also, the generated configuration is much larger:

```
:; linkerd inject --manual deploy.yml >deploy-manual.yml

namespace "myns" injected
service "mysvc" skipped
deployment "mydeploy" injected
:; du -sh deploy.yml deploy-manual.yml
4.0K    deploy.yml
8.0K    deploy-manual.yml
```